# URLs return 404 in Apache 2 using Ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Basically, any page I go to will return:

> 404 error

homepage works great but if I go to:

```
homepage.com/bananas
homepage.com/apples
homepage.com/apples/description1
homepage.com/fruits/tasty-fruits/shop-now
```

Any page UNDER the homepage will return a 404.

I'm transferring all of my files and database from a shared server to a server on Digital Ocean.

They were all working before I transferred over.

Any ideas why?  What do I need to edit?

Using Apache 2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Those URLs don't look like they match directly to existing files in the server file system, so likely some form of URL rewriting is in place - probably simply configured via .htaccess file. So check if you transferred that file correctly, check the hoster's documentation to see if you are allowed to use the rewrite engine/ mod_rewrite with your chosen plan, and if you have admin access to the server (nah, let's hope not - in that case, you should not have to ask ...), check if the higher-level configuration allows rewriting in .htaccess (AllowOverride must include FileInfo)

Comment: Are they php files or html files, does apache have read permissions on them, do you have php installed, is apache configured to guess php extension, is mod-rewrite used? By server, do you mean vps? If yes, run `find /var/www -type d -exec ls -la {} \;` and post results

Comment: @mugiseyebrows - Not sure if it is a VPS.  I ordered a droplet from DigitalOcean.  I executed your command via SSH and now it's busy doing stuff.  Everything on the server is PHP.  Will check on the read permissions.  PHP should be installed.  I believe I enabled mod-rewrite.

Comment: @CBroe My .htaccess file has AllowOverride All already.  Is it supposed to be at the top of the file or in a specific place within the file?

Comment: If theres `AllowOverride None` (which is default settings for security reasons) in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` all .htaccess files ignored

Comment: @mugiseyebrows Yea, I noticed "None" was set.  There's multiple instances of AllowOverrride None.  Which instance do I change and what do I change the "None" to?

Comment: I belive you can add configuration block for your specific directory

    `<Directory /var/www/homepage.com >
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>` if you have you files in `/var/www/homepage.com`

Comment: Now my site has a 500 error.  This is what I got in the config file.  As soon as I replaced "None" with "All", I get the 500 error.  `<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: @mugiseyebrows my next question would be, in .htaccess, what code do I need to enable mod_rewrite for a site that is on a subdomain?

Comment: you need virtual host for subdomain `https://askubuntu.com/questions/463618/setting-up-subdomain-on-ubuntu-server` and `AllowOverride All` inside <Directory /path/to/files > block in that virtual host (assuming you have rewrite rules in .htaccess file in root of subdomain directory)

Comment: to investigate what causes 500 error you need to look in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Yea, the subdomain exists because of the virtual host I created.  The folder where the subdomain exists is already in the <Directory> block.  What fixed it was looking at the error log.  Turns out I had some unneeded code in my .htaccess file which I took out.  Made sure I had mod_rewrite in there and then it worked.